# Oracle consolidate 2 rows into column

Tags: sql, oracle

Need help to display 2 rows as consolidated column

Made this image to illustrate the problem
Thank you for your help 
[image]

Comment: Why would you want to de-normalise your database?

Comment: Thanks, I need this info for a report, I am not changing the DB

Comment: Yes, I am using  Oracle (11G rel 2 and up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only require 2 cities then something simple might be to use analytic functions:

```
select distinct studentname
     , min(city) over ( partition by studentname ) as city1
     , min(street1) over ( partition by studentname ) as street1
     , case when min(city) over ( partition by studentname ) 
                  <> nvl( max(city) over ( partition by studentname ), 'x')
              then max(city) over ( partition by studentname ) end as city2
     , case when min(street) over ( partition by studentname ) 
                  <> nvl( max(street) over ( partition by studentname ), 'x')
              then max(street) over ( partition by studentname ) end as street2
  from my_table
```

Though I have to add that you probably shouldn't be doing this. What happens if a student has 3 addresses?

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you're thinking about this is not the correct one.

You should return the 2 rows for "Ted" and manipulate the output using your view/report code. That'd be much easier and would allow you to change your view/report really fast if your requirements change.